# EM_SETCUEBANNER doesn't work on RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, richtextbox

I've been using [`EM_SETCUEBANNER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761639%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to implement a place-holder on my `TextBox`es, it was working fine until I used it on [`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It doesn't display any text.

Here's my code:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
 public static extern Int32 SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string lParam);

    bool SetPlaceHolder(TextBoxBase control, string text)
            {
               const int EM_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1501;
                return Natives.SendMessage(control.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, text) == 1;
            }
```

using it on RTB returns `false` but `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` has value of `0`.

I can't find anything specific to RTB on [`Edit Control Messages`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff485923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should not surprise you too much, beyond [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761639%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a multi-line TextBox also doesn't support a cue.

Nothing you can't fix, it isn't very hard to do.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form, replacing the existing one.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class RichTextBoxEx : RichTextBox {
    public string Cue {
        get { return cue; }
        set {
            showCue(false);
            cue = value;
            if (this.Focused) showCue(true);
        }
    }
    private string cue;

    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e) {
        showCue(false);
        base.OnEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e) {
        showCue(true);
        base.OnLeave(e);
    }

    protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e) {
        if (!this.Focused) showCue(true);
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
    }

    private void showCue(bool visible) {
        if (this.DesignMode) visible = false;
        if (visible) {                          
            if (this.Text.Length == 0) {
                this.Text = cue;
                this.SelectAll();
                this.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(87, 87, 87);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (this.Text == cue) {
                this.Text = "";
                this.SelectionColor = this.ForeColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Would you grab the docs link from my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30246930/62576) and add it to yours (along with anything else you might want) so I can delete mine? Yours provides a solution, while mine just explains the problem. I'll gladly add a note that says I asked you to do so before deleting so that there's an audit trail. :-)

Comment: I don't see much of a reason to delete yours, just keep it around.

Comment: OK. I'm going to leave my comment here stand for a while, just to show I at least tried. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can try implementing this yourself:

```
public class RichTextWithBanner : RichTextBox {
  private const int WM_PAINT = 0xF;

  protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnTextChanged(e);
    this.Invalidate();
  }

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT && this.Text == string.Empty) {
      using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(m.HWnd)) {
        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, "Type Something", this.Font,
            this.ClientRectangle, Color.DarkGray, Color.Empty,
            TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot fix it in the RichTextBox itself, because you cannot set a cue banner on multiline edit or rich text controls.

From the documentation for [EM_CUEBANNER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761639%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (**emphasis** added):

> Remarks
>
> An edit control that is used to begin a search may display "Enter search here" in gray text as a textual cue. When the user clicks the text, the text goes away and the user can type.
>
> **You cannot set a cue banner on a multiline edit control or on a rich edit control.**

`GetLastWin32Error()` returns false because there's no error. The RichTextBox has already notified you that it's not processing the message (because `SendMessage()` returned false), but that's not an error - it's simply not processing the message. `SendMessage` returns the result of the message being sent; the meaning of that result depends on the message being sent, and in this case it means the RichTextBox doesn't support the message it received.